# Graph binary multiple bar with apexCharts

Tags: graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvHmW.png)

I am having a problem creating a binary chart like the image above. I have tried many solutions but can't find it.

Does anyone have any similar solutions or examples for me please. Thanks everyone

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.